Is there a way to delete captured variables?
I have gathered a long list of captured data variables. Is there a way to delete them all or some of them?
I could not find an option on the captured data module or in the advanced settings.
Please assist.
Variables generated on test executions



Name
Value




grabbedSearchValue
Monthly Premium


grabbedSearchValue
Plan Name


premium_plan_text
planCardPremiumHeader


ConfNum
Confirmation Number


ConfNum
86627290502


ConfNum
58509622994


generatedWhenDidThisHappenDate
12/01/2024


generatedPhoneNumber
2015830255


ConfNum
26305873944


generatedWhenDidThisHappenDate
12/31/2024


generatedPhoneNumber
2015511583


generatedFutureExpirationYear
2042




Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

Captured variables reside in memory while a test case is being executed. These variables are generally specific to the session and are available only duration of the test run. After the test case completes, the variables are automatically removed from memory.
